# Problem in Unity with missing texture with Instantiate( Resources.load ) method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem where a Instantiate a cube and set it's texture. Everything is good, but when I try to move the cube, it loses it's texture. Where am I wrong with my code?

At first I tried to load texture just with Resources.Load, but now after looking at forums changed it to Instantiate(Resources.Load). But it still doesn't help me.

```
void Start()
{
    texture = Resources.Load<Texture>("images/" + "(" + lastPic.ToString() + ")");
    textureClone = Instantiate(texture);
    pic = Instantiate(pic4, new Vector3(0, 1, 16), Quaternion.identity);
    pic.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = textureClone;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("GreyCube").Length == 0 && !flag)
    {
        pic.transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
        pic.transform.localScale = new Vector3( 18.8f, 11, 0);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the cube is moving it loses it's texture. It becomes a grey cube.

Comment: create a **prefab**, it should solve all problem

Comment: you can't use `Instantiate` on a `Texture` .. what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed it. The problem was with this line:

pic.transform.localScale = new Vector3( 18.8f, 11, 0);

Last digit which is 0 should been 1, like this:

pic.transform.localScale = new Vector3( 18.8f, 11, 1);